# Can definitions for functions be written accepting alternatives for arguments

Tags: function-construction

New to mathematica and also not entirely sure how to phrase my questions but basically I have a function I'm trying to write where several inputs will return the same value. For example,

```
function[ax, ax] = output1
function[ax, ay] = output1
function[ax, az] = output1
...
function[az, az] = output1
```

Is there a way to write this along the lines of:

```
function[ax||ay||az, ax||ay||az] = output1
```

instead of having to list all the possibilities out?

I tried this and it didn't seem to work so I was wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 12):

You almost got it right. You can use the pattern [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) ( | ) to do what you ask.

```
f[a | b | c, a | b | c] = "inputs ok";
```

or more exotically

```
g[(a | b | c) ..] = "inputs ok";
```

which allows one or more repetitions.

**Tests**

```
f @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c}, 2]
```

> ```
> {"inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok"}
> ```

```
g @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c}, 3]
```

> ```
> {"inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", "inputs ok", 
>  "inputs ok", "inputs ok"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have lists of acceptable arguments, you might want to do it like this.

```
listX = {1, 2, 3, x};
listY = {1};

f[x_, y_] /;
  MemberQ[listX, x] && MemberQ[listY, y] := "good"

f[__] := "evil"

f @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {x, 1}}
```

> {"good", "evil", "good", "evil", "good"}